# Select Containers having subitems in given range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Project:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | DEF |
| 3 | GHI |
| 4 | JKL |
| 5 | MNO |
| 6 | PQR |

Attachment:

| Id | Status | ProjectId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | 1 |
| 2 | a1 | 1 |
| 3 | a2 | 2 |
| 4 | a2 | 2 |
| 5 | a1 | 3 |
| 6 | a2 | 3 |
| 7 | a1 | 4 |
| 8 | a2 | 4 |
| 9 | a3 | 4 |
| 10 | a1 | 5 |
| 11 | a2 | 5 |
| 12 | a4 | 5 |

I'd like to get projectnames which has assignments only with statuses a1 and a2 (must have both of them) and doesn't havve assignments in statuses a3 and a4.
So the result should be:

```
GHI
```

What I've tried wass:

```
select distinct 
p.Name 
from 
Attachment a 
inner join Project p on p.Id = a.ProjectId 
group by 
p.Name, a.status 
having (a.Status = 'a1' or a.Status = 'a2'
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @VBoka, yes, I've had a few tries but I knew my queries are wrong and incomplete. I couldn't realize how to write these conditions. But you are write, I should post my queries to show that I am working on it myself, not just trying to push my task to others. My best try was: select distinct
p.Name
from
Attachment a
inner join Project p on p.Id = a.ProjectId
group by p.Name, a.status
having (a.Status = 'a1' or a.Status = 'a2')

Comment: Hi @user3057544 please add this try of yours in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exist|not exists` keywords to achieve this.

```
select [Name] from Project t1
where 
    exists (select 1 from Attachment where [Status] = 'a1' and ProjectId = t1.Id)
and
    exists (select 1 from Attachment where [Status] = 'a2' and ProjectId = t1.Id)

and 
    not exists (select 1 from Attachment where [Status] = 'a3' and ProjectId = t1.Id)
and
    not exists (select 1 from Attachment where [Status] = 'a4' and ProjectId = t1.Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `String_agg`,`Subquery` and `join` to get your desired result

```
SELECT name
FROM   (SELECT P.name,
               String_agg(status, ',')
                 within GROUP (ORDER BY status) Status
        FROM   project P
               join attachment A
                 ON A.projectid = P.id
        GROUP  BY P.name) t
WHERE  status = 'a1,a2'
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=425abe83ada4efa9aed197c58d0e54d4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use count distinct in combination with NOT IN:

```
select P.name
from Project P
left join Attachment A on P.id = A.ProjectId
where p.id not in (select A2.ProjectId 
                   from Attachment A2 
                   where A2.status in ('a3', 'a4'))
and A.status in ('a1', 'a2')
group by P.name
having count(distinct A.status) = 2
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70c89a8d03fbc2a292e217e2ffeb08ee)